# To disable all past dates except one particular date in JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker in which past dates are disabled. Since past dates are disabled I could not render a past date in that field.

Is it possible to render a past date and restrict past date on editing a datepicker field?

Comment: Can you share some code

Comment: Do not set a minDate, and instead handle this via the [`beforeShowDay`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option - that takes a callback function, that lets you decide for each individual date whether it should be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much for the help. It's working as expected‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

use this code for open a date picker

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtdate").datepicker({
         minDate: 0,
    });
    
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>DatePicker</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    Date :
    <input id="txtdate" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```